# VueJS v-repeat only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently use v-repeat to get my objects.
Inside i have one more v-repeat, but this should only repeat once. Is this possible?

```
<div v-repeat="companies">
{{name}}
   <div v-repeat="image: images"> // should only repeat once
     {{image.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you only want it to repeat once, why are you using `v-repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each company has many images and you only want the first image to show, here is a solution:

```
<div v-repeat="company in companies">
    {{company.name}}
    <img v-attr="src: company.images[0].url"> 
    {{company.images[0].name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are after, but here goes:

```
<div v-repeat="company: companies">
{{company.name}}
   <div>
     <img v-attr="src: company.image.url"/> 
     {{company.image.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

this is assuming there is one image per company